# IDEA: How to suppress warnings for spelling typos?

Tags: intellij-idea

One of my functions encrypts a string and one of my tests verifies that it took place. Naturally, strings like `sldjf982389` are not recognized as a valid English word, so `IntelliJ` complains.

If there a way to suppress these warnings without adding junk to the dictionary?

[image]

Comment: The only way to suppress the check without disabling the spell checker completely is to add this junk to the dictionary.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can disable that in the **Inspections** menu.  Click on the little green box at the top of source code, or navigate to File > Settings > Inspections, under the Project Settings divider.  You can then untick the box shown below.

[image: Screenshot of inspections in IntelliJ on Linux Mint]

Comment: Right. But will this disable all spellchecker? I certainly don't want that. I am only looking for a way to disable some custom typos w/o polluting the dictionary

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think we're given that luxury.  The granularity of the typo checking seems to be at the code or comments level.  So it stands to reason that you could disable the typo check at the code level.

Comment: The path `File > Settings > Inspections > Project Settings` is for older versions of Intellij IDEA. For newer versions like Intellij IDEA 2020, the path you are looking for is `File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Proofreading > Typo`

Answer (score 49):

You can use following @SuppressWarnings

For example idea is complaining about "contentid" that should be "contentId" according to him

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
public static final String ARG_CONTENT_ID = "contentid";
```

Comment: I would prefer something like this outside the source. It really seems that marking something explicitly as "not a spelling mistake" doesn't belong in the source, just to make one of the tools I use not provide a false positive.

Comment: Not a good answer at all. That too when you have to add code to fix it. The motive to disable the spellcheck here, not to supress it.

Answer (score 13):

SUPPRESSION facility for ANY inpection is built in :[image: Spelling Suppression example]

Pay attention to right arrows on the menus.

Comment: This works, except you cannot suppress the typo inspection for typos in a comment.

Comment: This no longer works in recent versions of IntelliJ.  You get "Spelling: Rename to..." and no option to suppress for statement.  In fact nothing in this thread is working.

Comment: PHPStorm 2020.3.2 recognizes `/** @noinspection SpellCheckingInspection */` at the top of file, but then we kill off spellchecking for everything.

Answer (score 8):

For Intellij IDEA 2020, the path to uncheck typos is `File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Proofreading > Typo`

Comment: It's better to disable the error of typos rather than change the style, thats why this answer wins for me.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, on intelliJ v2019.2
Go to `File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Errors and Warnings > Typo` and uncheck `Effects` check box. Fin!

Comment: This will just not render the warning underline, but when you hover on the word, the tooltip is still shown for the typo warning.

Answer (score 3):

## *Project-level* versus *Application-level* dictionaries

JetBrains is apparently steering people away from the complexity of inline-code spell-checker suppressions in favor of having the word added to the appropriate dictionary.

At first, I was also seeking the inline-code suppression, however, I can see that the dictionary philosophy is easier in the bigger picture of completing work and not becoming bogged down with inline-code suppressions and the clutter thereof e.g. for words that may commonly be used elsewhere in the project or several projects.

The option to use dictionary per-project or app-wide is available.

Find controls for per-project & app-wide dictionaries at menu item `Editor > Natural Languages > Spelling`. See the [*Dictionaries*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spellchecking.html#dictionaries) section of [*Spellchecking*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spellchecking.html) page of the IntelliJ manual.

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer IMO as you don't need to inline code to suppress the warning.  If you have Resharper installed, add your custom words here:  Extensions->Resharper->Options->Tools->Respeller->User Words.  Once you add your custom word(s), all the green typo warnings for that word will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to turn off spellchecking forever (for all projects) — I just found quick and dirty hack.

Go to *File* / *Settings*, then *Editor* / *Colors & Fonts* / *General*. Find settings for typo errors and set color for underline to color of background.

Comment: This will just not render the warning underline, but when you hover on the word, the tooltip is still shown for the typo warning.