# How can I disable spellcheck in IntelliJ for a line?

Tags: intellij-idea, spell-checking

I have this Kotlin code in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-212.5457.46, built on October 12, 2021:

```kotlin
// noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
private const val API_KEY = "aabbcc123" // noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
```

Clearly, "aabbcc" is not in any dictionary, so IntelliJ flags it as a typo. I generally want to keep spellcheck, I just want to disable it for that particular line. I don't want to add "aabbcc" to the dictionary as it would be a typo elsewhere.

After a web search, I tried the comments and annotation above, but IntelliJ still flags the typo.

When I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the typo, it only offers to add it to the dictionary, but it doesn't offer to ignore this instance.

How can I disable spell check per source line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67309273/715866) it sounds like this may not be possible. Your only option may be to add the word to your dictionary.